# zsh: strftime command not found

Tags: command-line, zsh, strftime

I am currently learning the zsh and now I wanted to use `strftime` but i get:

> `zsh: command not found: strftime`

I think I'm doin' something wrong, since I see people using that function all the time in their dotfiles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`strftime` is defined in a `zsh` module called `datetime`. The `zmodload` command loads modules from a colon-separated list of directories in `$module_path`.

On my system:

```
% echo $module_path
/usr/lib/zsh/4.3.10
% ls -l $module_path
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2009-11-05 01:03 zsh
% ls -l $module_path/zsh/datetime*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9828 2009-09-10 02:45 /usr/lib/zsh/4.3.10/zsh/datetime.so
% type -a strftime
strftime not found
% zmodload zsh/datetime
% strftime %Y-%m-%d 1271603087
2010-04-18
% type -a strftime
strftime is a shell builtin
% /bin/date -d @1271603087 +%Y-%m-%d
2010-04-18
```

Answer (score 2):

`strftime` is a C function, I believe `date` has all the same functionality on the command line.

See `man date` for more.

One uses the `--date=STRING` option to specify a date to format instead of getting current time.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who arrives here via Google, there's now a way to do this that doesn't require a `zmodload`. (I use it to [detect](http://blog.ssokolow.com/archives/2019/11/07/how-to-skip-the-fortune-command-when-your-shell-is-slow-to-start/)  when .zshrc is slow due to resource contention, so I don't want it to add new filesystem requests.)

```sh
${(%):-"%D{STRFTIME_STRING_HERE}"}
```

The gist of it is as follows:

1. Zsh allows `${VAR:-DEFAULT}` parameter substitution without a `VAR`.
2. Putting `(%)` before `VAR` enables expansion of the substitution tokens used in `PS1` and friends. (This is a very powerful feature because it also grants access to things like `%F{green}`. See "expansion of prompt sequences" in `man zshmisc` for more.)
3. Within a prompt-expanded string, `%D{...}` invokes `strftime(3)`.

I find `%D{%s}` particularly useful because `%s` retrieves the "seconds since the epoch" timestamp, which you can then do arithmetic on.

(Just be aware that, while `%s` is supported on Linux, AIX, Illumos, MINIX, OSX, and all BSD-family systems, it's not part of POSIX and isn't listed as supported in the online `strftime` documentation for Solaris, HP-UX, UnixWare, OpenServer, or the Windows libraries Cygwin and MinGW depend on.)